# Insert Case Apex - Disable Active Assignment Rules

Tags: apex, case, insert, assignment-rules

I am trying to insert a case in apex and set the owner to a specific user id.

However active assignment rules are rerouting the case.

In apex, how would I disable the use of active assignment rules upon insert as you can on the default case creation.

In the case history I can see the owner is going to the user id I set, but the assignment rule changes it on creation.

```
activeCase.OwnerId = createCaseOwnerId;
insert activeCase;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to disable the case assignment while inserting. You can do that using [DMLOptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_database_dmloptions.htm).

```
Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule= false;

activeCase.OwnerId = createCaseOwnerId;
activeCase.setOptions(dmo);
insert activeCase;
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw this in a trigger example and mistakenly thought it was trigger specific.